# PHP date formatting

Tags: php, date, formatting

I want to transform a date from this format: `01/07/09` to this `jan 07,09`.

How can I do that in PHP?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`strptime`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.strptime.php) to parse the value you've got, then [`date`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to output it in the format you want:

```
echo date("M d,y", strptime("01/07/09", "d/m/y"));
```

If you're on Windows, or using a version of PHP where `strptime` is not available (< PHP 5.1.0), then use [`strtotime`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) instead, but be careful to make sure your date is in a US English format (i.e. "01/07/09" means January 7th 2009, not 1st July 2009).

Also, if you really want `jan`, rather than `Jan`, then use [`strtolower`](http://uk.php.net/strtolower):

```
echo strtolower(date("M d,y", strptime("01/07/09", "d/m/y"));
```

Comment: Also note, `strptime` is not implemented on Windows.

Comment: @Brian, thanks - edited in a comment about using `strtotime` where `strptime` is unavailable.

Comment: you have the order of arguments for `date` mixed up. Should be: `date( $format, [ $timestamp ] )`

Answer (score 8):

I'm pretty sure this is what you need.

```
<?php echo date('M d, y', strtotime('01/07/09'));?>
```

Answer (score 2):

> Just pass the date variable to strtotime. See PHP [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for more.

```
$date = "01/07/09";
echo date("M d,y", strtotime($date));
```