# PHP convert time, day,month and year to a formatted string

Tags: php

I currently have:

```
$date = $this->item->publish_up;
echo $date
```

which returns: 2013-07-19 09:28:05

How can i convert this into text, for example Thursday, 
8th of November 2012 at 00:00?

I have tried:

```
$date = $this->item->publish_up;
$new_date = date('m-d-y', strtotime($date)); 
echo date("format",strtotime($new_date))
```

but it returns: f1970Thu, 01 Jan 1970 02:00:00 +020001am31

Any Help Greatly Apreciated

Comment: What are you trying to do with `"format"` string ? See here for the formats : http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: it was suggested online... almost everywhere i looked..

Comment: This is for the example. Of course it is not a real format ! Read the manual.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP date formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130600/php-date-formatting)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must escape `o`, `a` and `t`.
You can read more [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) in PHP Manual for `date` function

> You can prevent a recognized character in the format string from being
>   expanded by escaping it with a preceding backslash. If the character
>   with a backslash is already a special sequence, you may need to also
>   escape the backslash.

```
<?php
  echo date( "l, jS \of F Y \a\\t H:i A", strtotime( "2013-07-19 09:28:05" ) );
?>
```

Comment: @DawidvanderHoven Please, this is all described here : http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php. Too lazy to read ?

Comment: added just use `a` or `A` without escaping

Comment: oh wow, no to stupid to go look in the manual.. Sorry guys.. and thanks for all the help..

Answer (score 3):

```
$date = new DateTime($date);
echo $date->format('l, jS \of F Y \a\\t H:i');
```

Comment: @DawidvanderHoven, "a" char

Answer (score 0):

For 24 Hour format:

```
<?php
$date = '2013-07-19 09:28:05';
$newdate = date('l, dS \o\f F Y \a\t H:i', strtotime($date));
?>
```

If you were to echo `$newdate` it would display:

**Friday, 19th of July 2013 at 09:28**

---

12 Hour format with AM or PM:

```
<?php
$date = '2013-07-19 09:28:05';
echo $newdate = date('l, dS \o\f F Y \a\t gA', strtotime($date));
?>
```

If you were to echo `$newdate` it would display:

**Friday, 19th of July 2013 at 9AM**

Answer (score 0):

you can find your format string from here http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

```
echo date('m-d-y', strtotime($date));
```

m- month 01 through 12
d-day 01 to 31
y-year A two digit representation of a year

if you give 
    echo date('m-d-y', strtotime('now'));

o/p: 07-24-13