# How to display date in mysql TIMESTAMP?

Tags: php, mysql

I confuse about how to display TIMESTAMP like "1 March 2015 02:58 AM" from "2015-03-01 02:58:00" format in PHP

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP date formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130600/php-date-formatting)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo date('d M Y h:i A', strtotime('2015-03-01 02:58:00'));
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Take a look of all possibility

Answer (score 1):

You should try something like this, using [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function :

```
 date('d M Y h:i A', strtotime('2015-03-01 02:58:00'));
```

Comment: Edit to: date('d M Y h:i A', strtotime('2015-03-01 02:58:00'));