# How do i output month in words, like May instead of 05 in Cakephp

Tags: cakephp-1.3

How do i output *month in words*, like **May** instead of **05** in **CakePHP**, this below will output **05**, but i want May

```
 <?php foreach ($user as $user): ?> 
 <tr> 
 <td><?= $this->Time->format($user->modified, date('d-m-Y')) ?></td> 
 </tr>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP date formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130600/php-date-formatting)

Answer (score 0):

## PHP Way

Try using `F` in `date` function:

```
echo date('d F Y'); // Output: 24 May 2016
```

You can read more about date format at [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

## CakePHP Way

```
echo Time::now()->i18nFormat('dd MMMM yyyy'); // Output: 24 May 2016
```

Check out official documentation at [book.cakephp.com](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/time.html).

Comment: Thanks, it works with straight php but not with cakephp